# Correct object not passing to remote form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Each user of my site has their own profile page, which contains several items of the same class, call them job_items, which are instance variables of the job class. I'm working on adding edit functionality for each item. In each item I have

```
<%= link_to "edit", job_item, :onclick => "$('#edit_job').modal();", :remote => "true" %>
```

Which I want to bring up a modal containing the appropriate form:

```
...
<div class="modal-body">
 <%= semantic_form_for(job_item, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

However, any time I click edit, it doesn't matter which job_item I clicked edit within, the modal appears with a form for the same job_item, namely the first on the page. How can I set which job_item I want to be edited in the form? I'm confused because if I hold my mouse over the edit link, the correct job url appears, however it is not being passed to the javascript modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you have more than one element with the id "edit_job" in your page? If so, `$('#edit_job')` will just choose the first one, because it assumes the ids are unique. You could fix this by making sure the ids are unique

```
:onclick => "$('#edit_job_#{job_item.id}').modal();"
```

and changing the corresponding element ids accordingly.

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton man. Here I was thinking there was something basic I didn't understand about the scope of variables. I just used erb in the id of my modal and did what you said above, and now everything is working.